# Probability of infinitely many events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $x_n$ identical and independent and $P(x_n)>r>0$, show $P(x_n$ happens for infinitely many $n)=1$.

I know this follows from second lemma of borel contelli, but is there a way not to use that lemma?

Comment: What are $x_n$'s? Are they events or random variables?

Comment: @kabomurphy Events

Comment: Independence is crucial, so the best way to prove this is to use Borel-Cantelli. Any attempt to prove it from scratch is likely to imitate the proof of Borel-Cantelli Lemma.

Comment: @kabomurphy is the condition here stronger than borel contelli though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event that only finitely many of the events $\ \left\{x_n\right\}_{i=1}^\infty\ $ occur is $\ \bigcup_\limits{i=1}^\infty\bigcap_\limits{j=i}^\infty\Omega\setminus x_j\ $. Since $\ \bigcap_\limits{j=i}^\infty\Omega\setminus x_j\subseteq\bigcap_\limits{j=i}^{i+k-1}\Omega\setminus x_j \ $ for all positive integers $\ i\ $ and $\ k\ $, and the latter events have probablity less than $\ (1-r)^k\ $, it follows that the probability of $\ \bigcap_\limits{j=i}^\infty\Omega\setminus x_j\ $ is zero for every $\ i\ $.  Thus, since the event that only finitely many of the events $\ \left\{x_n\right\}_{i=1}^\infty\ $ occur is a countable union of events of zero probability, it also has zero probability itself.

I'll leave it for others to judge how closely this mimics the proof of the Borel-Cantelli lemma, or whether it is any simpler.